# How can I apply PCA to KNN?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, pca, k-nn

I want to know the do not want to how to use library

I will denote a $n\times p$ data matrix by $X$, where $n<p$. That is, each row of $X$ is one sample data with $p$ feature variables.

---

By using singular vector decomposition method, I can decompose $X$ into $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $X=ABC$, where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix satisfying $A^TA=I_{[n\times n]}$, $B$ is a $n\times p$ matrix whose diagonal elements are all non-negative and real but non-diagonal elements are all zeros, and $C$ is a $p\times p$ matrix such that $P^TP = I_{[p\times p]}$.
Without the loss of generality, I assume that $B$ is obtained satisfying that the diagonal elements of $B$ is descending order, i.e., $b_{i,i} > b_{j,j}$ for $i<j$.

---

The score matrix, $S$, is obtained by $S=XC$, whose dimension is $n\times p$.

In order to reduce the dimension of variables, we do as follows:
Denoting the $i$-th column of $C$ by $c_i$, which is a loading vector with respect to $i$-th principal component.
Hence, deleting $c_{k+1}$ to $c_{p}$, I can obtain $C_k = [c_1~c_2~\cdots~c_k]$.
The dimension-reduced score matrix, $S$, is obtained by $S_k=XC_k$.

---

In this situation, how can I run KNN?
Actually, I already made my own KNN code, whose input is trainX, trainY, and testX, and whose output is evaluatedY.
I want to compare (i) basic KNN and (ii) dimension-reduction-applied KNN.

I obtained error rate of (i) basic KNN using 5-fold cross validation method.

```
yhat = myKNN(trainX, trainY, testX);
errRate = myErr(y, yhat);
```

To obtain error rate of (ii) dimension-reduction-applied KNN, is the following correct?

```
trainS= myDimensionReduction(trainX, k)
testS= myDimensionReduction(testX, k)
yhat = myKNN(trainS, trainY, testS);
errRate = myErr(y, yhat);
```

where myDimensionReduction is a function that converts a data matrix $(n\times p)$ into a reduced data matrix $(n\times k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good. However, what I doubt about is the `myDimensionReduction` function. When you apply the PCA on the test data, you have to multiply $X_{test}$ by the matrix $C$ that has been generated from the training data, *not by the test data*. This is to stress that the test data should not be used in any step of the training process. If this is what the `myDimensionReduction` function does, that is alright. Otherwise, if this function creates the matrix $C$, then it is not right.

I know you didn't ask for the library, but I think it makes sense in here: The whole philosophy of scikit-learn is to create objects that correspond to algorithms, use the training data with the `fit` method and apply the `transform` method to the test data.

Comment: Before using PCA, when testing a vector $x_q$ whose size is $1\times p$, I considered the $K$ nearest neighbors are $x_i$'s with the smallest $\lVert x_i-x_q\rVert$. However, when using PCA, when testing $x_q$, is it fine to consider the $K$ nearest neighbors as $K$ data $x_i$'s with the smallest $\lVert x_i C_k - x_q C_k\rVert$ ?

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, denoting by $c_{i,j}$ the $i$-th row and $j$-th column of $C_k$, is it reasonable to estimate the contribution of a variable $x_i$ by $\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{k}c_{i,j}^2}$.

Comment: I think that both your claims are correct